# Converting a list of dictionaries into a list of tuples

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, tuples, key-value

I am a rank beginner, so appreciate any help. I have a list of dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'name': 'John', 'gender': 'Male', 'marks': [20,30,40]}, 
       {'name': 'Lynn', 'gender': 'Female', 'marks': [20,30,40,50,60]},....]
```

How would I convert this list into a list of tuples?. So something like:

```
[(John, Male, [20,30,40]), (Lynn, Female, [20,30,40,50,60]),......]
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
new_list = []

for dic in lst:
    new_list.append(tuple(dic.values()))

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like comprehension.

```
lst = [
    {'name': 'John', 'gender': 'Male', 'marks': [20,30,40]},
    {'name': 'Lynn', 'gender': 'Female', 'marks': [20,30,40,50,60]}
    ]

lst = [tuple(d.values()) for d in lst]
```

https://onlinegdb.com/Vo4PZYL7y